# Set color for expandable list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I just tried the current Google sample for ExpandableListiew: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

This sample seem very simple and easy to use.

But what I would like to do is to say that change back ground color for child element and group element.
it doesn't uses any child_row.xml , group_row.xml.
please tell me the right way to do.

Thank a lot for any information.

Comment: refer this link http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

you can define new style for the expandable list view like below...

```
<style name="Widget.MyExpandable" parent="android:Widget.ExpandableListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_background</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/ex_listview_stroke</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/color_foreground</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
</style>
```

in hear list_selector_background is the drawable selector file in which you can define several states for the EXList view like stander and pressed etc...,

and to have different background for the child and parent you need to create separate... drawable background file for childview.xml and parentview.xml